# How can I communicate with WCF from Delphi using Named Pipes Binding

Tags: wcf, delphi, delphi-2007, netnamedpipebinding

Can I use Delphi 2007 to communicate with a WCF service using the netnamedpipebinding ?

If so, then how?

Comment: Please let us know if you get this to actually work.  I'll be surprised and impressed.  It'd be lovely if you could write up a tutorial for the benefit of the delphi/.net community.

Comment: Just as a follow up, I had tried to use RemObjects SDK from http://www.remobjects.com/ro/ 

but I could not get it to work.  It would support Named Pipes between two Delphi Clients though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you create a COM-visible proxy for your service using .NET (and WCF!), then consume it from Delphi as you would any COM object.

There are several reasons why implementing a native client for a WCF service listening on a NetNamedPipesBinding endpoint is extremely complex. See http://blogs.charteris.com/blogs/chrisdi for more details.

Comment: This would have been a good solution.  We decided to not communicate this way though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to do this, as long as you can get Delphi 2007 to communicate with the Windows named pipes.

Here's an [article at Delphi 3000](http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_2918.asp?SK=) about how to use Delphi to communicate with named pipes, including some code samples.

Since named pipes are a basic core feature of Windows NT/XP/Vista, Delphi should be able to communicate with those no problem (reading + writing).

Does that help at all?
Marc

Comment: I tried this and received the error "Pipe did not respond"  I have also tried the pipes library from error and I have also tried the more extensive pipes code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512366/how-do-i-send-a-string-from-one-instance-of-my-delphi-program-to-another .  In that one, I received a windows error 109.